# mongodb - the service is not responding to the control function?

Tags: mongodb

I just starting to research mongodb, I create MongoDB local service and can't start, I use windows 10, can anyone explain me the reason? Thanks very much

[image]

Comment: what are the steps you followed? Can you give some more details? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss the picture, after I setup mongodb.msi successfully, my steps are:
- create folder C:\mongodb\data and C:\mongodb\logs
- run mongod --dbpath C:\mongodb\data
- run mongod --logpath C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
And when I run mongod.exe, I receive ' waiting for connections on port 27017' and waiting forever :(
After that I check MongoDB service local, start and receive that error [image above]

Comment: I did many method, reinstall MongoDB service local, try add mongo.cfg file but...

Comment: if you are getting "waiting for connections on port 27017" that means your server is running just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo version 4.2.6
Windows 10

> The service is not responding to the control function.

The last line in the `mongod.cfg` file was 'mp:'.  Commented it out.  '#mp:'

Service now starts